# How do I get Percent of Total in SQL Rollup?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of data in SQL Server 2014 that I need to rollup into subtotals AND come up with a percent-to-total for each row. Here's a simplified example of what I need to do:

Example Data:
`SELECT * FROM myTable`

```
Week    Category    Collection  Sales
1       Red         Good        4
1       Red         Bad         5
1       Blue        Good        2
1       Blue        Bad         2
2       Red         Good        3
2       Red         Bad         1
2       Blue        Good        4
2       Blue        Bad         1
```

The rollup part is straightforward:

`SELECT Week, Category, Collection, Sum(Sales) as Sales 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY Week, Category, Collection WITH ROLLUP`

```
Week    Category    Collection  Sales
1       Red         Good        4
1       Red         Bad         5
1       Red         NULL        9
1       Blue        Good        2
1       Blue        Bad         2
1       Blue        NULL        4
1       NULL        NULL        13
2       Red         Good        3
2       Red         Bad         1
2       Red         NULL        4
2       Blue        Good        4
2       Blue        Bad         1
2       Blue        NULL        5
2       NULL        NULL        9
NULL    NULL        NULL        22
```

Now, what I would like to get to is a rolled up percent-to-total for each section of the rollup. Like this:

```
Week    Category    Collection  Sales    % Total
1       Red         Good        4        .4444 (4/9)
1       Red         Bad         5        .5556 (5/9)
1       Red         NULL        9        .6923 (9/13)
1       Blue        Good        2        .5 (2/4)
1       Blue        Bad         2        .5 (2/4)
1       Blue        NULL        4        .3077 (4/13)
1       NULL        NULL        13       .5909 (13/22)
2       Red         Good        3        .75 (3/4)
2       Red         Bad         1        .25 (1/4)
2       Red         NULL        4        .4444 (4/9)
2       Blue        Good        4        .8 (4/5)
2       Blue        Bad         1        .2 (1/5)
2       Blue        NULL        5        .5556 (5/9)
2       NULL        NULL        9        .4091 (9/22)
NULL    NULL        NULL        22
```

*Note, I don't need to show the dividing numbers shown in parenthesis. That is simply to make it easier to see the calculation.

I'm not really sure how to approach the SQL to get me this kind of result. I'd be very grateful if someone could get me pointed in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is the solution to your problem. [A solution proposed in other site](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=49775)

Comment: Thank you for the link. It poses a similar question, but it too has no working answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a method that uses a Common Table Expression (CTE) to pre-calculate the possible denominators using analytic functions, then performs an aggregate rollup.  In the aggregate query, the percentage is determined by using the coalesce operator in the denominator, along with grouping sets in the rollup such that at each stage of the rollup the coalesce function gets the next successive denominator value. You can check out the query and results below or view the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/53bc5/1) to see the setup and query in action.

```
with t1 as (
select week
     , category
     , collection
     , sales
     , sum(sales) over (partition by week, category) cat
     , sum(sales) over (partition by week) w
     , sum(sales) over () o
  from mytable
)
 select week
     , category
     , collection
     , sum(sales) sales
     , sum(sales)/coalesce(cat, w, o, sum(sales)) [% sales]
   from t1
  group by rollup(
        (week, o)
      , (category, w)
      , (collection , cat))
order by 1, 2, 3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/53bc5/1/0)**:

```
|   week | category | collection | sales |  % sales |
|--------|----------|------------|-------|----------|
| (null) |   (null) |     (null) |    22 |        1 |
|      1 |   (null) |     (null) |    13 | 0.590909 |
|      1 |     Blue |     (null) |     4 | 0.307692 |
|      1 |     Blue |        Bad |     2 |      0.5 |
|      1 |     Blue |       Good |     2 |      0.5 |
|      1 |      Red |     (null) |     9 | 0.692307 |
|      1 |      Red |        Bad |     5 | 0.555555 |
|      1 |      Red |       Good |     4 | 0.444444 |
|      2 |   (null) |     (null) |     9 |  0.40909 |
|      2 |     Blue |     (null) |     5 | 0.555555 |
|      2 |     Blue |        Bad |     1 |      0.2 |
|      2 |     Blue |       Good |     4 |      0.8 |
|      2 |      Red |     (null) |     4 | 0.444444 |
|      2 |      Red |        Bad |     1 |     0.25 |
|      2 |      Red |       Good |     3 |     0.75 |
```

Taking Yogesh's solution and fixing it's deficiencies below yeilds the same results as my solution above.  See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b3d9f/2) to see it in action:

```
SELECT Week
     , Category
     , Collection
     , Sum(Sales) as Sales
     , Sum(Sales)
     / (select sum(sales)
          from myTable s
         where (m.category is null or Week = m.Week)
           and (m.collection is null or Category = m.Category)
       ) as [% Total]
FROM myTable m
GROUP BY Week, Category, Collection WITH ROLLUP
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Really great content!

Comment: wow, the second example that you added is working really really well. Its a bit more efficient too for my dataset. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: It helped me lot. Saved so much of my time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `subquery` with rollup:

```
SELECT Week, Category, Collection, Sum(Sales) as Sales,
       1.0 * Sum(Sales) / (select sum(sales) from myTable where Week = m.Week and Category = m.Category) as [% Total]
FROM myTable m
GROUP BY Week, Category, Collection WITH ROLLUP;
```

However, be aware with *divide by zero* error, you would need to add some kinds of prevention such as `case` expression or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This gets me part of the way there but will only work for getting percent to Category total, relative to Collection. It gets me pointed in a right direction though.